# xcode is not building static libraries properly (functions are not in them)

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, xcode4, static-libraries, otool

Basically I am able to create and compile a static library in xcode4 but the functions are not being read in by otool. I managed to do it *once* so that it would work but every other time since then it has failed so I know I must be missing an obvious step.

What I currently do is create a new view based application in xcode4, I then add a new target (Numbers), to Numbers I add a source file called File.c and its content is:

```
static int Get10()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Then I compile it (making sure I've selected Numbers |iPhone 4.3 Simulator in the build scheme drop down).

But when I run otool -S on libNumbers.a I get no results:

> size of ranlib structures: 0 (number 0) object offset  string index

I know there should be some stuff there because if I run otool -S on the correctly built libNumbers.a I get some numbers instead of 0s:

> size of ranlib structures: 16 (number 2) object offset  string index
>   136            0 136            7

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly, I've tried backtracing what I did with the succesful lib compile I made but haven't really found anything to indicate why the functions compiled with that one but not these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `static` if you want to use the function outside of the translation unit it is defined in. You want external linkage for the function instead by just leaving out the `static` part (external linkage is the default for functions).

Comment: oh that worked! Thanks so much! Must mean when it actually worked for me that one time I left out the static declaration on the function. But this doesn't make sense to me, why won't statically declared functions work?

Comment: @meds: `static` means the function has internal linkage and thus can't be linked to from outside that translation unit (i.e. source file). You'll want to use `static` for e.g. helper functions that are only used in that source file to avoid naming conflicts in the linking stage.

Comment: I guess [this site](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter4/linkage.html) gives some overview.